# Generating dynamic XML in Razor

Tags: c#, xml, razor

I am using Razor outside of ASP.NET to generate XML documents from a template. I have the following code:

```
<event>
    <timeouts trigger='@Model.TriggerTimeout' />
    <parameters>
    @foreach (var parameter in Model.Parameters) {
        <@parameter.Key>@parameter.Value</@parameter.Key>
    }
    </parameters>
</event>
```

where Model.Parameters is just a name/value collection. My expected output should be:

```
<event>
    <timeouts trigger='100' />
    <parameters>
        <name1>value1</name1>
        <name2>value2</name2>
        <name3>value3</name3>
    </parameters>
</event>
```

but what I am actually getting is:

```
<event>
    <timeouts trigger='100' />
    <parameters>
        <name1>value1</@parameter.Key>
        <name2>value2</@parameter.Key>
        <name3>value3</@parameter.Key>
    </parameters>
</event>
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the secret sauce that I need to apply to make the dynamic elements close properly?

**EDIT**
So now my model evolves to have multiple events, and my Razor code looks like this:

```
<events>
@foreach (var _event in Model.Events) {
    <@_event.Name enabled='@_event.Enabled'>
        <timeouts trigger='@_event.TriggerTimeout' />
        <parameters>
        @foreach (var parameter in _event.Parameters) {
            @:<@parameter.Key>@parameter.Value</@(parameter.Key)>
        }
        </parameters>
    </@_event.Name>
}
</events>
```

the output should be:

```
<events>
    <event1 enabled='true'>
        <timeouts trigger='100' />
        <parameters>
            <name1>value1</name1>
            <name2>value2</name2>
        </parameters>
    </event1>
    <event2 enabled='false'>
        <timeouts trigger='100' />
        <parameters>
            <name1>value1</name1>
        </parameters>
    </event2>
</events>
```

but it actually is:

```
<events>
    <event1 enabled='true'>
        <timeouts trigger='100' />
        <parameters>
            <name1>value1</name1>
            <name2>value2</name2>
        </parameters>
    </@_event.Name>
    <event2 enabled='false'>
        <timeouts trigger='100' />
        <parameters>
            <name1>value1</name1>
        </parameters>
    </@_event.Name>
</events>
```

**SOLUTION**
Through a *lot* of trial and error, I eventually tracked down the missing secret sauce. The opening dynamic XML element needed a `?:` prefix to render the closing element correctly. Most weird.

```
<events>
@foreach (var _event in Model.Events) {
    @:<@_event.Name enabled='@_event.Enabled'>
        <timeouts trigger='@_event.TriggerTimeout' />
        <parameters>
        @foreach (var parameter in _event.Parameters) {
            @:<@parameter.Key>@parameter.Value</@(parameter.Key)>
        }
        </parameters>
    </@_event.Name>
}
</events>
```

Comment: I've tried recreating this scenario and it's working fine for me in a normal `.cshtml` file.  What are you using to parse the razor files?

Comment: Did you try `@:</@(_event.Name)>` ?

Comment: Also, it is interesting that you are using Razor outside of MVC. Have you considered [Runtime-T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx)

Comment: I did try that, but I got the following error : ":" is not valid at the start of a code block. Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

Comment: @KirkWoll I am using RazorEngine (http://razorengine.codeplex.com/). We went with Razor as we use it for our ASP.NET MVC applications.

Comment: @KirkWoll I've also tried running the Razor views in an ASP.NET MVC4 test harness, and I get exactly the same result - the second-level XML elements don't get their closing tag, instead the Razor code is written verbatim to the output.

Comment: Consider using LINQ to XML instead of Razor here.

Comment: The scenario doesn't work - I need users to be able to edit the Razor templates so that they can customise the output. It's entirely possible that I would change the output to be JSON for a single customer, and Razor gives me that flexiblity.

Comment: Can you please explain how you're creating the xml documents?

Comment: I'm using the standalone Razor engine (installed from NuGet) inside my business layer; the Razor view itself is stored in the UI, and gets passed through to the business layer for rendering. It's quite flexible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write `</@(parameter.Key)>` to stop Razor from thinking that that's an email address.

Comment: Unfortunately that only gives me the an output of <name1>value1</@(parameter.Key)>

Comment: @DavidKeaveny: Try adding `@:` to the beginning of the line.

Comment: I've also tried </@{parameter.Key}>, but that gives me an output of <name1>value1</@{parameter.Key}>. It looks like the </ is stopping Razor from parsing the last value. I've tried splitting it over multiple lines without success either.

Comment: Ah, that did it for that part of my problem.

Comment: I finally tracked down the offending part of my code - the <@_event.Name> element, although it generated the correct line of code for itself, still needed the @: as a prefix so that the closing tag would also be written. *very* annoying, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll update the question with the final working solution.