# Return XML using a Razor Page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How can I create an XML (in particular I'm trying to build sitemap.xml) using a Razor Page?

I've read MSDN [Introduction to Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio#tabpanel_qRfKG5ySAy_visual-studio)  but it only shows how to create HTML pages. When I just use basic XML like shown in [Generating dynamic XML in Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741835/generating-dynamic-xml-in-razor?rq=1) something goes wrong...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a new Razor Page with the following contents.

```
@page
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    @*Include your static urls*@
    <url>
        <loc>https://example.com/my-static-page</loc>
    </url>
    @*Dynamically include pages generated from your database*@
    @foreach(var article in articles)
    {
        <url>
            <loc>https://example.com/article/@article.Url</loc>
            <lastmod>@article.Modified.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")</lastmod>
        </url>
    }
    @*You get the idea*@
</urlset>
```

The XML declaration coming before the `@{Layout=null;}` is essential!  Otherwise XML parsers won't work correctly and this will all be for nothing.

Bonus:
To make the route /sitemap.xml work you'll need to add this.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => 
            {
                options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Sitemap", "sitemap.xml");
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: This post does not really answer the question (ignoring the fact that question is way too broad). Showing how return XML from ASP.Net MVC is least interesting portion of sitemap generation (and answered many times already for all combinations of .Net runtimes ASP.Net/ASP.Net MVC/ASP.Net-core.

Comment: The point is that it can be done with Razor Pages and that there's a pitfall that isn't obvious to be avoided.  I do admit I made the question too broad.  I'll revise it when I get a moment.

Comment: Please read the question - "make a dynamic sitemap" (the fact you've wrote the question does not mean you see what it asks *as written*). About returning XML - you may want to use better search engine - either Google or Bing (https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+aps.net+core+return+xml+file+razor) would show how to return XML file using Razor...

Comment: You realize this isn't a Razor View, but instead a Razor Page?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio

Comment: "How to return XML using Razor page" has nothing to do with sitemaps...

Comment: My point was that the search engine result didn't have an answer for doing this in, specifically, Razor Pages.  I assumed you were going to link me to a search result proving your point.  When you didn't I assumed you must have mistaken a Razor View with a Razor Page.  I apologize for the confusion.  Also, thank you for helping me with structuring of the question.  I was doing this quick and dirty and that wasn't appropriate.